# Complexish If Else always returns result of last Else

Tags: crystal-reports

This is the first part of a 3 formula query that forms a text sting in a report that forms a product catalogue.

I have extensively researched the If/Else syntax and can't get anything but the final "half Pallets of" to return. Where am I going wrong?

```
If isNull({OITM.SalPackMsr}) OR {OITM.SalPackMsr} = "Pallet" then 

(if isNull({OITM.SalPackMsr}) OR {OITM.SalPackMsr} = "HPallet" then 

(if isNull({OITM.SalPackMsr}) OR {OITM.SalPackMsr} = "Pack" then

(if isNull({OITM.SalPackMsr}) OR {OITM.SalPackMsr} = "Carton" then

"Carton(s) of " 
else 
"Pack(s) of ") 
else
"Half Pallets of ") 
else 
"Full Pallets of ")
else
"Half Pallets of ";
```

Comment: What should be returned when `isNull({OITM.SalPackMsr}` is true?

Comment: Yes! This is what was bringing me undone! I have answered below

Answer (score 0):

Have removed the isnull reference and the below syntax is working.

```
     If {OITM.SalPackMsr} = "Pallet" then "Full Pallets of " else " "
     +
     IF {OITM.SalPackMsr} = "Carton" then "Cartons of " else " "
     +
     IF {OITM.SalPackMsr} = "HPallet" then "Half Pallets of " else " "
     +
     IF {OITM.SalPackMsr} = "Pack" then "Packs of " else " "
     +
```

IF {OITM.SalPackMsr} = "2HPallet" then "Half Pallets of " else " "